# Kdb generate a new column from a column of 1,-1 and null, it should generate fills 1s and -1s but it should have 0ss if the direction changes

Tags: kdb

I have a table `t: ([] dir: 0n 1 0n 0n -1 0n 0n 0n 1 1 -1 0n -1 0n)`

I want to generate a new column based on `dir` it should basicly fills the null values however I dont want the `newDir` column to change from 1 to -1 immediately and vice versa, if the direction changes it should be zero (for the first change direction input). So for example the resulting column should be like this:

`t: ([] newDir: 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 -1 -1)`

How can I achive this new column in kdb?

The `fills` method does not solve the problem obviously. I also tried to get the direction changes but I could not achieve the result because assume that I have the following input `1 0n -1 0n 1` I would like to get `1 1 0 0 1` . If I update every direction change to `0` then I would get `1 1 0 0 0` but since the first direction change only make the direction `0` it should not affect the next `1` or `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom "fills" using scan

```
q)update newDir:0f^{$[0=x+y;0f;x^y]}\[dir]from t
dir newDir
----------
    0
1   1
    1
    1
-1  0
    0
    0
    0
1   1
1   1
-1  0
    0
-1  -1
    -1
```

Comment: Hi Terry, Than you very much! Could you simply describe what x and y stands for in this formula?

Comment: It's iterating through the values: x is the previous value, y is the next value. If they sum to zero that means it has switched from -1 to 1 or from 1 to -1

Answer (score 1):

This gets the same output you expect. You can use `differ` to find only the values that change and then get a running sum on that:

```
update newDir:sums ?[differ dir;dir;0n] from t
dir newDir
----------
    0
1   1
    1
    1
-1  0
    0
    0
    0
1   1
1   1
-1  0
    0
-1  -1
    -1
```

Comment: Hi Thomas thank you, but this solution failed for some cases. For example: 

`dir: 0n 0n 0n 0n 0n -1 0n 1 0n -1 -1 0n 1 1 0n 0n 0n`

`nDir: 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0`

it should be

`nDir: 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 1`